# Boost.Test error messages are no more shown in error list of VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I am using Boost.Test Unit Test Framework for native C++ projects. All is working fine, but I've got one issue after upgrading to Visual Studio 2010: The messages about failed tests are no more shown in the error list after the tests ran as a post build step. This is a pity since the combination of Boost.Test with native C++ project came closest (although still beeing far away) to the comfort I am used to from unit testing managed projects. I am using the configuration recommended by the authors of Boost.Test [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/usage-recommendations/dot-net-specific.html). Can anyone help with this minor but a bit comfort lessening issue?

Regards,

Paul

Comment: Has the compiler error-message format changed btw. VS2010 and previous versions, so that the IDE cannot parse the Boost.Test messages? What do you see in the Output Window?

Comment: To clarify the issue a bit: The messages about failed tests are shown in the output pane of VS properly. It's the entry in the *error list* pane what is missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2005 Build output for compiler errors looks like this:

```
|.\ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(8) : error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
```

Whereas Visual Studio 2010 compiler errors look like this in the output window:

```
|1>ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(8): error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
```

(Edit: See the comment by [gbjbaanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13744/gbjbaanb) about the `>1`.)

Now, crosschecking what BOOST_ERROR outputs (you can use a simple printf to reproduce if you have your exe in the post build step):

VS 2005:

```
|./ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(8): error in "test_TEST": check true == false failed [1 != 0]
```

VS 2010:

```
|1>  ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(10): error in "test_TEST": check true == false failed [true != false]
```

Slight difference, but not too much and testing further with a manual printf:

```
printf("ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(00): error : in \"test_TEST\": check true == false failed [true != false]" "\n");
                                  ^^^ .. Note colon here
```

We also get VS 2010 to recognize this output as error:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_TEST)
{
    printf("ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(00): error : in \"test_TEST\": check true == false failed [true != false]" "\n");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( true, false);
}

1>------ Build started: Project: ut_TEMPLATE, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  ut_TEMPLATE.cpp
1>  ut_TEMPLATE.vcxproj -> ....\UnitTests\ut_TEMPLATE\..\..\..\Release\ut_TEMPLATE.exe
1>  Running 1 test case...
1>ut_TEMPLATE.cpp : error : in "test_TEST": check true == false failed [true != false]
1>  ut_TEMPLATE.cpp(9): error in "test_TEST": check true == false failed [true != false]
1>C:\Programme\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command ""....\\ut_TEMPLATE.exe" --result_code=no --report_level=no
1>C:\Programme\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

*So it would appear you/we/Boost.Test needs to tweak it's output so that the VS2010 IDE still recognizes the error message.*

Comment: the 1> represents which build the line refers to, so when you build on a quad-core PC, and you have several projects in the solution, it will build 4 of them simultaneously, and prefix them with 2> 3> etc.

Comment: Thank you all... I admit that this time I decided to ask the community before doing much investigation on my own. In the office I'm still using VS2008 (with boost 1.43 customized and built manually) where the error messages from Boost.Test are recognized properly. At home I've got VS2010 + boost 1.44 installed from binaries provided by boost consulting. Also, VS2010 seem to provide much more fine-grained control over the build process directly from the IDE - so before I start to tweak around Boost.Test I need to check the other possibilities. Will report on success...

Comment: Please file a ticket Boost.Test

Comment: @paul_71: I agree with Gennadiy, someone should file a ticket :-)

Comment: With boost 1.49, this (surely) unintended behavior is still there. I'd really appreciate if this was fixed in the official release of Boost.Test since it prevents us from using the precompiled official release out-of-the-box...

Comment: @GennadiyRozental´: this really annoying problem is still present in 1.52. Not that it was difficult to fix, it just makes patching and recompiling boost libraries necessary, which is something I'd like to avoid. Is there a specific reason why it is not fixed in the official distribution?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to wait for a release and want to fix the formatter by yourself

open

BOOST_PATH\boost\test\impl\compiler_log_formatter.ipp

change (line 163 in boost_1_46_1)

```
output << "error in \"" << test_phase_identifier() << "\": ";
```

to

```
output << "error : in \"" << test_phase_identifier() << "\": ";
```

and recompile boost with bjam again.

```
cd BOOST_PATH
bjam.exe
```